# Setting return-path on Email post mimeMessage creation

Tags: java, email, mime-message

I've googled around and it looks like the standard way to set the return-path of an email (so that bounces go to a different address from the sender) is via Properties object like this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.from", "bounce@domain.com");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

// set from/to/subject of the mail here.
```

Is there a way to set the return-path AFTER mimeMessage object is created? the mail architecture I am working with creates an empty mail, then based on what type of mail it actually is, sets the rest of the fields related to the mail. I only want certain kinds of mails to bounce, not all, so I would rather not set return-path before the message object is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean to determine if it should bounce or not.

```
Boolean Bounce;
String BounceAdr;

// Set Bounce = true / false depends on mail created

if (Bounce == True) {
BounceAdr = "bounce@domain.com";
prop.put("mail.smtp.from", BounceAdr);
} else {
BounceAdr = null;
prop.put("mail.smtp.from", BounceAdr);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, that doesn't help with the way the code base is set up b/c 1 base class is what creates the Properties and Sessions and Empty Mail, the classes that inherits the Base class calls the empty mail creation method, and then sets the to/from later.